Как автоматически открывать Windows 10 Menu
Как сделать при нажатии клавиши "windows" открывалось
Windows 10 Menu (Start10), а не это:


Что значит "как"? Переформулируйте пожалуйста вопрос, очень непонятно, как вам помочь

Меню пуск в стиле Win 7, я правильно понимаю?) Если да, то скопируйте до запятой и в гугл) или поясните что именно нужно, из вопроса не понятно..
p.s. так как мое меню выглядит совсем иначе (в стиле вин 7) я такое и предположил.

Удалите стороннее меню, перезагрузитесь и пользуйтесь обычным.
Можно попробовать найти стороннего меню и отключить горячую клавишу.

Спасибо вам большое
